# Quasar Framework, Electron, and Serialport: indexOf Error

Tags: electron, quasar, node-serialport

I'm setting up a test project with Quasar, Electron, and serialport. When starting the application with a minimal serialport test, I get the following error:

```
vue-router.esm.js?85f8:2128 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.getFileName (bindings.js?d8c5:178)
    at bindings (bindings.js?d8c5:82)
    at eval (win32.js?0965:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/win32.js (vendor.js:340)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (index.js?3983:6)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/index.js (vendor.js:252)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
```

The error even happens when I only include the serialport package without doing any more. It seems to be a basic problem. Code to reproduce the problem:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import SerialPort from 'serialport';

@Component
export default class Index extends Vue {
  test() {
    console.log('test', SerialPort);
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried everything I could find here, in the Quasar forum, etc. pp.: electron-rebuild, trying to config serialport as an external dependency, ...

I'm not quite sure if the rebuild process is working as expected, but I don't know what to check to make sure it does. The electron example project with serialport is working for me. Maybe it is a Quasar related thing?

Can I get more information on the rebuild process? I tried different combinations with specifying the version, but nothing is helping.

[image]

I also [asked](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/issues/2089) this question as an issue in the serialport repository, but adding it in the vue.config.js doesn't work, because I'm using Quasar as the CLI option.

[image]

I think the main problem is how to rebuild serialport properly for electron when Quasar is in place, which seems to be not working as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had quite some trouble getting Serialport to run in Quasar and Electron, but I got it to work. The solution is not really pretty and might break in the future.

As you wrote, you need to run electron-rebuild. You can execute it by running "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild". You should also put in in your package .json in the "scripts" section

```
"install": "electron-rebuild"
```

I used the Electron preload script to put serialport in the window object. [Here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/electron-preload-script) is the documentation on how to enable this. In the electron-main.js, you also need to add the [following line](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397)

```
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false;
```

If missing, electron will fail to load.

In electron-preload.js, put this

```
window.serialport = require("serialport");
```

You can now use serialport in your Quasar project by using window.serialport.

Another problem I encountered was the fact that Quasar changes the package.json while packaging the project and removes the install script so electron-rebuild does not run while building and the packed version does not work. I managed to fix this by adding a "beforePackaging" Hook into the electron part of quasar.conf.js

```
//Top of the file
const path = require("path");
const crossSpawn = require("cross-spawn");
...
electron: {
  ...
  beforePackaging(params) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const runner = crossSpawn(
        path.join("node_modules", ".bin", "electron-rebuild"),
        [""],
        {
          stdio: "inherit",
          stdout: "inherit",
          stderr: "inherit",
          cwd: params.unpackagedDir
        }
      );

      runner.on("close", () => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  },
}
```

Maybe somebody has a nicer solution to this, but I hope, this helps.

Comment: Many thanks. Your suggestion is working. It is a dirty hack, I think. But at least a working one. :) I still have problems with the rebuild because it doesn't work automatically. But it is working manually, so I will use it as it is for now.

Comment: Thank you!!! I spent all afternoon trying to figure this out. Your answer is the only thing that worked.

Comment: After some further development and testing, I encounter the following problem: electron-builder is fording the electron-rebuild in the devDependencies section. If I move the package to this location, the beforePackaging function cannot find the node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild path. Maybe because only non-dev dependencies are installed? Is there a solution/workaround for this problem?

Comment: I would like to let future readers know that this awesome answer also works for [node-hid](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid) with a minor detail: add `cfg.externals = { "node-hid": 'commonjs node-hid' }` in `quasar.conf.js` > `electron` > `extendWebpack(cfg)`. The rest is the exact same thing except that you should type `node-hid` instead of `serialport`. But it works perfectly. I spent hours trying to fix this so I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
beforePackaging (params) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const runner = crossSpawn(
        '..\\..\\..\\node_modules\\.bin\\electron-rebuild -f -v 9.3.1 -w serialport',
        [''],
        {
          stdio: 'inherit',
          stdout: 'inherit',
          stderr: 'inherit',
          cwd: params.unpackagedDir
        }
      )
      runner.on('close', () => {
        resolve()
      })
    })
  },
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
   beforePackaging(params) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          const runner = crossSpawn(
           "npx electron-rebuild", [""], {
              stdio: "inherit",
              stdout: "inherit",
              stderr: "inherit",
              cwd: params.unpackagedDir,
            }
          );
          runner.on("close", () => resolve());
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you packaging and building whole project,You can use electron-preload.js to put serialport in the window project.

`window.serialport = require("serialport");`

Then You can now use

`const SerialPort = window.serialport.SerialPort;`